# Arduino analogreadserial command Java

Tags: java, arduino

I am relatively new to using the Arduino, and I am looking to write a program in Java for it.

I have already found the code for interfacing the Arduino with Java on their website, but I am wondering if there is a way to write methods such as the Arduino `AnalogReadSerial` command in Java?

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino software is natively in C++, which is actually fairly similar to Java in my opinion. If you have found a way to interface with Java, there should be libraries included.